# Program with embedded python fails to start with python 2.7.11 amd64

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-c-api, python-embedding

I have a windows program that has python embedded in for scripting purposes

If I install Python 2.7.10 64 bit (python-2.7.10.amd64.msi), and run the program, it works fine.

If I install Python 2.7.11 64 bit (python-2.7.11.amd64.msi), and run the program, it fails with the error "`missing module site`". However, if I run the program from a batch file, and add "`set PYTHONPATH=C:\python27\lib`", the program starts up and runs normally.

The only difference is the version of python installed, and we are running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, SP1 with 3GB RAM, and a quad core processor.

Is it possible that the python 2.7.11 install is not setting a required registry entry, or that my program is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 bugs with python 2.7.11 that should have been resolved in python 2.7.12. We hit the same issue in pythonnet recently:

https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/156